# Setting download path to existing profile selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium4

My issue is when i pass profile as an option:

```
            options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\shimon\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
        options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 3")
```

The download set path seems to take no affect

```
            prefs = {"download.default_directory": "C:\\Users\\shimon\\PycharmProjects\\project_2\\downloaded\\files"}
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

If I remove the profile

```
            options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 3")
```

It works well.
Is there any solution for that? couldn't find any related issue.

Answer (score 1):

You might try the following:

```py
options = ChromeOptions()
current_directory = os.getcwd()
download_directory = f"{current_directory}/temp"

prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": download_directory,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,  # To auto download the file
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
}  # It will not show PDF directly in chrome}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = # initialize driver

if not os.path.exists(download_directory):
    os.makedirs(download_directory)

params = {"behavior": "allow", "downloadPath": download_directory}
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.setDownloadBehavior", params)
```

also, you should check:

1. If replacing `\\` with `/` in your path works (noticed that issue on Windows sometimes)
2. If the Path exists and has the correct permissions